# generate random value for hidden input field

Tags: javascript, html

is it possible to generate a random value (number, symbols, letters) for an input field (preferably hidden) on click?
I need to come up with an idea to simulate somewhat of a conformation number. Unfortunately I cant save the values into a db.

I thought of something like: 
input before: `<input id="randomizeme" value=""/>`

javascript or jquery solution:

```
var randomtext=$('#randomizeme').attr('value');

anybutton.click(){
    randomtext="some numbers randomly scrambled together";


}
```

input output:

```
<input id="randomizeme" value="some numbers randomly scrambled together"/>
```

this is probably all garbage but i hope it helps, as for the tags im not sure either

Comment: You should expand the question, because it is not currently clear (to me at least) what is wanted. Also, these tags are too broad, and not overly visible, so the question should be retagged, but I don't know with what, because I don't understand the question. What programming language is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>S.O. 4169522</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var gRandLength = 7;

    $(document).ready(function() {   
        $('#button').click(function() {   
        var num = Math.floor(1 + (Math.random() * Math.pow(10, gRandLength)));
        $('#input').val(num);
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body onload='onload()'>
    <form>
        <input type="text" value="" id="input" />
        <input type="button" id="button" value="Generate"/>
    <form>
</body>
</html>
```

Sample Output:

[image]